# How to compare two strings which contain backslashes in Python

Tags: python, string, ocr

I am working with the module ocr from Python and some image return this string `'921,\u201d'`. (The image is a date which looks like 9/21/2015)

Now, if I try to execute this

```
a == '921,\u201d'
```

Python automatically escapes the inverted slash (`\`) in the hardcoded string and the comparison is not equal.

How can I compare two ascii strings without Python interpreting some substrings as unicode characters?

The length is 6
The error is 
self.assertIn(res0, [r'921,\u201d', "Feb 21, 2015"])
AssertionError: u'(921,\u201d' not found in ['921,\u201d', 'Feb 21, 2015']

Thanks. \u201 is a only one char.

Comment: We're going to need a more precise description of the strings involved, as well as what Python version you're on. What's the `len` of the string the OCR tool is giving you? Does it contain a literal backslash, or does it just `repr` that way? Does it contain literal single quotes at each end?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a raw string literal.

```
a == r'921,\u201d'
```

This allows you to use literal backslashes without having to escape them (the only restriction is that a string still can't end with an unescaped backslash).

You can also escape the backslash by prepending a backslash to it:

```
a == '921,\\u201d'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to decode using 'utf-8':

```
>>> '921,\u201d'.decode('utf-8')
u'921,\\u201d'
```

Comment: String objects do not have a decode method in Python.